# How to use Qt Test output in Bamboo?

Tags: unit-testing, qt, xunit

Is there a way to use the Qt Test output generated with -xunitxml in Bamboo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JUnit parser works with the output generated as long as the test output files has the extention *.xml. The problem seems to be that using any other extention except *.xml for the unit test output files will result in the Bamboo not reading the output files and reporting that the build was testless.